# C# best way to debug a worker crew

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-debugging

One of my applications is heavily using the worker crew model. Several threads are created that do essentially the same thing to different pieces of data.
What is the best way to debug this?
Is there a way in Visual Studio to have a breakpoint based on line of code and thread name?
Edit: Actually the desired behaviour would be that only one thread of worker crew stops at the wanted place and that all other workers keep on going.

Comment: You can set a condition on a breakpoint in which you can simply check the name of the the current Thread and if it equals to a certain name like System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name == "Thread1". Next to that, if you use TPL including AttachToParent, there are many inbuild debugging tools that can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [conditional breakpoints in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce.aspx). Your condition could be `Thread.CurrentThread.Name == "MyThread"` for example.

Answer (score 1):

VS.NET 2010 has bultin [support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee410778.aspx) for debugging task-based parallel apps. These pages can help you too: [Walkthrough: Debugging a Multithreaded Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157784.aspx) or [Debugging Multithreaded Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164746.aspx).